# Angular: How to load component by name

Tags: angular

I want to load different kind of component, depending on the type of the column. The idea is to load specific component to show some specific data.

The column metadata is the following :

```
export enum Columntype {
    Standard,
    Component
}

export class ListHeader {
    id: String;
    label: String;
    type?: Columntype = Columntype.Standard;
    url?: String;
}
```

Component name is in the 'Url' string in the case of a 'Component' type (type = 1), And I would like to load the corresponding component dynamically in the following table :

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor='let key of columns'>
                {{ key.label }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let row of rows'>
            <td *ngFor="let key of columns">
                <span *ngIf='key.type == 0'>
                    {{ row[key.id] }}
                </span>
                <span *ngIf='key.type == 1'>
                    <{{ key.url }}></ {{ key.url }} > <!-- should load the component, but this don't work-->
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [Portal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview):

> A Portal is a piece of UI that can be dynamically rendered to an open
>   slot on the page.
>
> The "piece of UI" can be either a Component or a TemplateRef and the
>   "open slot" is a PortalOutlet

**update:**
If you are looking for a solution without Material CDK, you can use the [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), which is a bit more complex implementation if the underlying ComponentFactoryResolver, but achives the same functionality:

> Component templates are not always fixed. An application may need to
>   load new components at runtime.
>
> This cookbook shows you how to use ComponentFactoryResolver to add
>   components dynamically.

Comment: Any way to do it without Angular Material ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ComponentFactoryResolver for dynamically loading components. You can have different ng-template for each component. Then you can check if type = 1 then load that template.